# Get the number of value occurrences within last X rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm writing a nagios plugin for a service of mine, I want to check how many of last X actions resulted in an error.

I've came up with this query that does the job, but selecting from select seems messy to me, I'd like to know if there are other, perhaps more elegant solutions.

```
SELECT 
  count(id) 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) as T 
WHERE error IS NOT NULL;
```

This counts the number of rows within last 10 in the table (id is an ever incrementing sequence) where error field is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is pretty elegant.  The query has to do two things:  identify the last ten rows and then count the number of errors.  This structure captures exactly what it needs to do.

You can get rid of the `where` clause and just use:

```
select count(error)
```

Subqueries in the `from` clause are very useful and there is no reason to think of them as "inelegant".

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance, good point about counting on the field directly instead of WHERE clause.